# How to use record from renderer function as store for combo inside editor ExtJs Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I have a grid with with cell editing plugin:

```
Ext.define('MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',        
    title: 'MyGrid',
    emptyText: __('no_data'),        
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 1
    },
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                queryMode: 'local'
            },
            renderer: function(value) {
                // this I wont to use value as store combo
                return value;
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Value in renderer function is an array. How to use it as store in combo inside editor?

Comment: could you clarify the question, put a sample of the data you are trying to edit

Comment: `{Work: example@gmail.com, Own: example@gmail.com}`
It is object of emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using widget column with combobox.

```
{
            xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
            flex: 1,
            text: 'Email',
            editor: {},
            widget: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                queryMode: 'local',
                displayField: 'email',
                valueField: 'email',
                editable: false,
                value: 0,
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: 'afterComboEmailRender',
                    change: 'onComboEmailChange'
                }
            }
        }
```

And I dynamically set store from cell record to combo after it render.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the value in the column would be the value that the user selects from the combobox. If this was the case and the values that you are selecting from will be the same for all the columns, then you can create a store for that combobox and bind it.